# How can I fix this deprecation error?

Tags: errors, deprecation

I get this error form the functions.php file How can I fix it?

Error Level: E_DEPRECATED
Message: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated
File: wp-includes/functions.php
Line: 2182
Request: /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=fluent-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an error message from the 'fluent mail' plugin. So you need to contact the plugin support page.

Comment: I think it just caused it but the error is not on their side, it is in the functions.php file

Comment: The plugin is calling a function that is defined in the functions.php file, and that call is not being done properly. Still think it is in the plugin. Disable the plugin and see if you get the same error.